# Using Storyboard reference for TabBar is not displaying the TabBar item image and title

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uistoryboard

I am creating an TabBar controller app via Storyboard. I am using Storyboard reference object to link another storyboard for the 3rd tab item. It is working correctly but i didn't get the title and image for that Tab item. I can see image and title in the storyboard but while running I am unable to see those in the simulator.

Main Storyboard:
[image]

Second Storyboard:
[image]

App:
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why you are using another storyboard ? can't you implement that second stroryboard VC to existing one ?

Comment: I need to use it! That will be developed by another developer so that I can integrate it easily..

Comment: Check my answer then if it can help :)

Answer (score 2):

Drag `Tab Bar Item` from the `Object Library` to `UIViewController` in the second Storyboard.

Fill up `Title` and select `Image` in `Bar Item` in the second Storyboard.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should programatically instantiated that storyboard and then populate the tab bar controller with its root views as you always have, laid out here in the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/).

You can instantiated storyboard like,

```
 let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "YourFormStoryboard", bundle: nil)
 let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("formViewController") as! YourFormClass
```

so, instantiate storyboard like this and manipulate your tabbar controller programatically.

> It is better to not use multiple storyboard if not required.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But storyboard design keeps me easy for integration :). Also I am trying to use that new feature but unfortunately it has bug!

Comment: You're welcome.... :) you can't do it from interface builder i think because when you drag from tabbarcontroller to VC then it make tabbar item on that VC and you can customize it from that VC by clicking on that bar item. Now you are draging to storyboard reference then there is no VC to make bar item. so it's not create bar item but you can click at then it will move to that storyboard i think.

Comment: actually in the storyboard reference there is tab bar item from where i set the title and image as shown in Main storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

here you are Embed a nvigation  controller between tab bar controller and your view controller . so now your view conterller in your navigation controller not in tab bar controller.[image]

if you want to show tab bar image and item then give segue from tab bar controller to your view controller  :)